# ping not calculating microseconds anymore

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, ping, kernel

Today I decided to update my old `el5` kernel with yum after years. What I didn't know is that the kernel that was running was custom and after updating and rebooting the network drivers started to fail loading and so I decided that booting from an older kernel would spare me more time than trying to fix the custom one.

The previous, custom kernel was `2.6.39` and the current, downgraded one is `2.6.18-308.11.1` (both `x64`).

The network drivers are loading correctly again after the downgrade, but now `ping` is not measuring in the microseconds range anymore. Instead, it'll only round up/down to the nearest milisecond integer, like this:

```
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
```

Is there any known settings in the kernel that makes this happen? I searched a bit on Google but didn't find a single individual with the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would even matter since ping itself isn't really that accurate. The margin of error for ping is really in milliseconds, and it increases with distance. Anything in the range you show matters not a bit to any real application.

Comment: This server is used for network monitoring and now all the graphs are very hard to read. Previously: http://puu.sh/l1krf/78cd380e88.png now: http://puu.sh/l1kvB/e1d23c3973.png

Comment: Microseconds in ping times are meaningless data, Gathering meaningless data is a waste of time. Graphing meaningless data just produces meaningless graphs. You can re-jigger the graphs to line up correctly with the current data. You should have probably just dropped the microseconds on the original. What really matters for ping times is probably closer to 10 milliseconds, and, if I were doing this, I would round to the nearest 10 milliseconds and graph that.

Comment: Honestly ping isn't anywhere near accurate enough for it to matter.

Comment: @Daniel, no kidding, but I have been around long enough to know that there are thick-headed management-types who thrive on this sort of thing. It's no use arguing with them, but maybe, just maybe, you can talk them into something a little more reasonable. I have had managers who would have had coronaries if faced with this situation. Hence my suggestion of rounding to the nearest 10 milliseconds.

Comment: @RonMaupin What do you mean when you say ping isn't accurate? Are you saying it has a large standard deviation, or are you expecting it to measure something it doesn't really measure?

Comment: @Spiff, ping is only designed to show connectivity. Ping requests and responses themselves have variable overhead per hardware, OS, and drivers which can be quite wide. Comparison of gross ping time between two systems could be an indicator of a change in the route, a briefly congested buffer due to abnormally large packets queued in front of a ping could slow it down, but that event may be a one-off.

Comment: @Spiff,  a long-term trend, throwing out large deviations, and using the nearest 10 milliseconds may produce something useful about increasing congestion on a path, but ping isn't truly accurate enough to produce anything useful from the sort of graphs provided in the comment.

Comment: ping is by default the lowest priority traffic on the network.  In no way shape or form should ping be used to get accurate latency.  It's just going to be put lower on the list.

Comment: Like I said, my only issue was with the readability of the graphs, not with the precision of the responses themselves (which indeed are meaningless). We also didnd't develop the program ourselves so reprogramming it to compensate on the graphs is not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like high resolution timers (sub millisecond) didn't fully land in the kernel until 2.6.21.

You'll probably have to re-upgrade your kernel to something released within the last 8.9 years. :-)

See http://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers or Google for "Linux high resolution timers", or check the time(7) man page.